# ORM relationships (possibly Kohana specific)

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

I have a couple of models, one is a notification and one is a severity.  Notifications have a severity.

My Notifications table in my database (simplified) is as follows

```
id => int
message => text
severity_id => int
```

My Severity table has the following columns

```
id => int
name => varchar(20)
```

In my Notification model I have the following relationship

```
protected $_has_one = array(
    'severity' => array(
        'model' => 'NotificationSeverity',
        'foreign_key' => 'id' )
);
```

I don't know how to tell it to use the severity_id as this side of the relationship though.

I want to be able to access the severity directly from the notification object i.e. $notification->severity->name etc.

I have also tried by setting a has_many relationship on the other side of this relationship as follows so that I can access a list of all notifications with a particular priority.

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'notifications' => array( 'model'  =>  'Notification', 
    'foreign_key' => 'severity_id' )
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  I can change the database and/or code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same `foreign_key` on both sides of the relation. Also *has_many* needs the corresponding part to be *belongs_to*.

has_many means "ownage" just like has_one does while belongs_to means "being owned". So you can't have one site owning the other, but the other owning the one as well (unless you have *has_many_through*). This means that when one side has_one/has_many models, the corresponding side needs to belong(s)_to.

Notification

```
$_belongs_to = array(
    'severity' => array(
        'model' => 'NotificationSeverity',
        'foreign_key' => 'severity_id',
    )
);
```

NotificationSeverity

```
$_has_many = array(
    'notifications' => array(
        'model' => 'Notification',
        'foreign_key' => 'severity_id',
    )
);
```

Comment: why belongs to rather than has one?  It doesn't make sense to have a belongs to relationship when the notification does not belong to the severity.

Comment: The notification has the `severity_id` saved in its table, so it does belong to it, doesn't it?

Comment: The notification has a severity, thats the only relationship in my eyes.  The severity should not really know about the notification.

Comment: Your method does work, I am just trying to understand why I need to set up all these extra relationships when all I want to say is the notification has one severity.

Comment: I think the language is a bit tricky here (and I feel I am unable to completely express myself). `belongs_to` means the key is saved in this model, where as `has_one`/`has_many` expect the key to be saved in the corresponding model

Comment: hmm ok, thanks.  I do find the language a little confusing myself, but your method seems to work as I want so for now I will stick with this.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. As for the "extra": a relationship is always between (at least) two parties